# Load the API library in chrome app (for google wallet)

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, android-pay, google-chrome-app

According  to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/tutorial#2) I should be able to include `<script src="https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js"></script>` in html of my packaged app, but I received an error:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not
>   explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Also I've tried to attach buy.js (which I just copied from mentioned url) but it also produces an error in buy.js:

> Refused to frame
>   'https://checkout.google.com/inapp/frontend/app/payments.html?formFactor=DES…extension://ihligbifffjddjffdiapccakkdglodcj&rti=i:48847aba&rt=o:-519cd794'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:".

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. This buy.js is a simple cross-app messaging script which talks to internal Google In-App Application inside Chrome.

> You must package the buy.js library with your app, and load the library from its location in your package.

Check [this](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/google_wallet.html#how-to) for more info

Comment: yep. i did try to include it into app.. That what I've meant by 'attach'

Comment: if you look inside buy.js, you'll see that it doesn't open any window, it just interacts with the internal app. Did you include the proper version of buy.js library (https://raw.github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/master/in-app-payments/buy.js) or attached yours (https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js)?